# How can I fix this issue with my python text-based game?

Tags: python

```
import os
import random


battle = True

nameA = "John"
nameB = "Marcus"

maxhpA = 50
hpA =50 #amount of health
atkA = 5 #attack damage
potA = 10 #potion number
luckA = 30
goldA = 0 #amount of player_gold

maxhpB = 50
hpB =50 #amount of health
atkB = 5 #attack damage
potB = 10 #potion number
luckB = 30
goldB = 0 #amount of player_gold
def draw():
    print("XX-----------------------XX")
def clear():
    os.system("cls")
    
clear()

def stop():
    input(">")

def healA(amount_healed):
            global hpA, maxhpA, nameA
            if hpA + amount_healed < maxhpA:
                hpA += amount_healed
            else:
                hpA = maxhpA
                print(nameA + "'s HP refilled to " + str(hpA) + "!")
                
                
def healB(amount_healed):
            global hpB, maxhpB, nameB
            if hpB + amount_healed < maxhpB:
                hpB += amount_healed
            else:
                hpB = maxhpB
                print(nameB + "'s HP refilled to " + str(hpB) + "!")
                
                
def turnA():
    global hpA, hpB, atkA, atkB, nameA, nameB, potA, potB
    
    choice = input( nameA + "'s turn >")
    
    if choice == "1":
        
        hpB -= atkA
        print(nameA +" attacked!")
        print(nameB + " took " + str(atkA) + " damage!")
        stop()
    if choice == "2":
        if random.randint(1,100) < int(luckA):
            hpB -= 2*atkA
            print()
            print(nameA +" preformed a special attack!!")
            print(nameB + " took " + str(2*atkA) + " damage!")
            stop()
        else:
            print(nameA + " missed their special attack!")
            stop()
    if choice == "3":
        if potA > 0:
            potA -= 1
            print(nameA +" used a potion.")
            healA(25)
            input(">")            
        else:
            print("No potions!")
            stop()    
    else: #issue
        print("Invalid option!")
        turnB()
        clear()  
        stats()
        stop() 
    

def turnB():
    global hpA, hpB, atkA, atkB, nameA, nameB, potA, potB
    
    choice = input( nameB + "'s turn >")
    
    if choice == "1":
        hpA -= atkB
        print(nameB +" attacked!")
        print(nameA + " took " + str(atkB) + " damage!")
        stop()
    if choice == "2":
        if random.randint(1,100) < int(luckB):
            hpA -= 2*atkB
            print()
            print(nameB +" preformed a special attack!!")
            print(nameA + " took " + str(2*atkB) + " damage!")
            stop()
        else:
            print(nameB + " missed their special attack!")
            stop()
        
    if choice == "3":
        
        if potB > 0:
            potB -= 1
            print(nameB +" used a potion.")
            healB(25)
            stop()            
        else:
            print("No potions!")
            stop()
    else: # issue is here!
        print("Invalid option!")
        turnB()
        clear()  
        stats()
        stop()  
        
    
        
def stats():
    print("Name:    {0:15}{1}".format(str(nameA), str(nameB)))
    print("HP:      {0:15}{1}".format(str(hpA), str(hpB)))
    print("ATK:     {0:15}{1}".format(str(atkA), str(atkB)))
    print("POTIONS: {0:15}{1}".format(str(potA), str(potB)))
    print("LUCK:    {0:15}{1}".format(str(luckA), str(luckB)))
    
    draw()
    
    print("1 - ATTACK")
    print("2 - RISKY ATTACK")
    print("3 - USE POTION (25HP)")
    
    draw()

    
while battle:
    stats()
        
    turnA()
    
    clear()
    
    stats()
    
    turnB()
    
    clear()
```

Hello. This is a python text-based game I have been working on. It is very simple but there is an error I just cannot figure out. The game works very simply, player A has their turn, and then player B gets theirs, to be expected.

All the options work fine, but I am getting an error with the "else" parts of the turnA and turnB functions. If you play a move that's invalid, I want the player to have another chance to make their move, but it is causing issues as seen in the image below. every second input is now counted as an invalid input.

[image]

Comment: @TomasWhelan In the next step you should try to write this program without using `global`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code looks similar to this:

```py
    if choice == "1":
        # Do something
    if choice == "2":
        # Do something
    if choice == "3":
        # Do something
    else:
        # Do something
```

With this syntax, your else statement is applying when the choice is not Option 3. Instead, you should use:

```py
    if choice == "1":
        # Do something
    elif choice == "2":
        # Do something
    elif choice == "3":
        # Do something
    else:
        # Do something
```

This will step through each choice and *then* run the else condition if none of the `choice` options match.

Also whilst you're here, have a read around [Python Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp). This project will be a good way to introduce yourself to some new concepts within object oriented programming e.g. storing properties such as HP within objects.